# Clicking on color swatch, images are not loading on product listing page in magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, color-swatches, product-detail-page

I have added color swatches for my Configurable products. On product detail page when we click on color swatches the product images not changed properly as per color.so please fix this.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below and run below commmand

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

[image]

Comment: this is already done @gohil but it showing this 
error :
swatch-renderer.min.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).AddFotoramaVideoEvents is not a function